# In Pandas, how to make a PivotTable for counting and skip replicates?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

In Python3 and pandas I have a dataframe like this:

```
IdComissao      SiglaComissao       NomeMembro
12444           CCJR            Abelardo Camarinha
12444           CCJR            Abelardo Camarinha
12448           CAD             Abelardo Camarinha
12448           CAD             Abelardo Camarinha
12453           CMADS           Abelardo Camarinha
12453           CMADS           Abelardo Camarinha
12453           CMADS           Abelardo Camarinha
13297           CPI-InvTer      Abelardo Camarinha
8509            CFC             Abelardo Camarinha
8509            CFC             Abelardo Camarinha
13149           CPIATFC         Abelardo Camarinha
12444           CCJR            Vaz de Lima
12445           CFOP            Vaz de Lima
12445           CFOP            Vaz de Lima
12445           CFOP            Vaz de Lima
12454           CAE             Vaz de Lima
12455           CDD             Vaz de Lima
8501            CCJ             Vaz de Lima
8503            CAP             Vaz de Lima
8509            CFC             Vaz de Lima
8509            CFC             Vaz de Lima
8511            CEP             Vaz de Lima
8515            CFO             Vaz de Lima
8515            CFO             Vaz de Lima
8515            CFO             Vaz de Lima
8515            CFO             Vaz de Lima
8515            CFO             Vaz de Lima
8519            CSOP            Vaz de Lima
8521            CEDP            Vaz de Lima
```

I am looking for a way to count how many times each name "NomeMembro" has an item "SiglaComissao", without repeats

For example, the name "Abelardo Camarinha" has six types of "SiglaComissao" and the name "Vaz de Lima" has 11 types

Please, is there a way to make a PivotTable to count items without repeats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
df.groupby('NomeMembro')['SiglaComissao'].nunique()
```

Which returns:

```
NomeMembro
Abelardo Camarinha     6
Vaz de Lima           11
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to also sort from highest to lowest?

Comment: `df.groupby('NomeMembro')['SiglaComissao'].nunique().sort_values(ascending=False)`